# root login must be su instead of loginning directly in Redhat , how to set?

Tags: linux

In RedHat , I want to login with other user firstly in SSH, such as the user input when installing OS , then su - root , instead of being able to login with root directly in SSH 
How to set in command line and config files ? I have no UI .

Comment: Wrong site. You're looking for [unix.se] or [su] instead. This site is for programming related quesions.

Comment: So sorry , Thanks for your reminder . I will post related questions in Unix later, but for this question , let me close it when I get the answer

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: For future reference: When you're told your question is off-topic here, it's off-topic NOW, not when you choose to make it so. You don't get to wait until it pleases you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to stop remote login through ssh by root. You just edit configuration file of ssh server.

```
  # vim /etc/ssh/sshd_config
    #PermitRootLogin yes
```

remove # and replace yes to no

```
     PermitRootLogin no
```

after that restart sshd deamon.if you are in centos6/5/RHEL6/5/ubuntu

```
   # /etc/init.d/sshd restart
```

or If your are in centos7/RHEL7/Ubuntu

```
   # systemctl restart sshd.service
```